Plotly: How can I show information on a certain range of data on a graph?
I must say right away that I am new to python and have only just come across data analytics in it.
Working with Pandas and Plotly, from the csv file, I take the data to create a dataframe (next - DF) in Pandas, then using loc[::10] I take every 10 lines. The DF file itself consists of many thousands of rows and dozens of columns, but I'm only interested in 2 columns: time and data. Then I pass these two columns to Plotly: "fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = DF[column Time], y = DF[column Power], mode='line+markers'))", where x is time, y is data. The values in data can be either negative, zero, or positive.
Question: how can I display information on the Plotly chart about how long the negative and zero values ​​lasted in total?
Let's say:
0 00:00:01 5
1 00:00:02 10
3 00:00:03 9
4 00:00:04 -0.5
5 00:00:05 -0.4
6 00:00:06 -0.3
7 00:00:07 0.0 - 4 sec duration
8 00:00:08 5
9 00:00:09 10
10 00:00:10 11
This needs to be shown on the graph. There can be a lot of such values.
I will be very grateful to you, English is not my native language.
I haven't tried anything, I have no idea how it could work. Perhaps other libraries are needed.
upd:I inserted an example picture. I need to know how long the red intervals last (15 minutes, 30 minutes or 1 hour) and reflect this on the graph.
enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

better show example data and expected image. And put it in question, not in comments, and not as link to external portal.

Added pic in post.

Remember to post sufficient amounts of sample data to help in the resolution of your problem. So, basically, you need to calculate the durations of the data you're interested in or lack thereof. After this, you can plot and annotate the plot. Here is an example where I've set the annotation if and only if the duration is larger than 60 seconds:
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

data = {
    'Time': [datetime(2023, 5, 1, 12) + timedelta(minutes=10 * i) for i in range(20)],
    'Power': [5, 3, 2, -1, -2, -3, 0, 0, 5, 2, -1, -2, 3, 5, 0, 0, -1, 0, 2, 3]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df['Duration'] = df['Time'].diff()
df['Shifted Duration'] = df['Duration'].shift(-1)
df['Group'] = (df['Power'] > 0).astype(int).cumsum()

negative_durations = df[df['Power'] <= 0].groupby('Group')['Shifted Duration'].sum()

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Time'], y=df['Power'], mode='lines+markers', name='Power'))

annotations = []
for group, duration in negative_durations.items():
    start_time = df[df['Group'] == group]['Time'].min()
    if duration.total_seconds() > 60:
        annotations.append(dict(
            x=start_time,
            y=0,  
            xref="x",
            yref="y",
            text=f"{duration}",
            showarrow=True,
            arrowhead=1,
            ax=0,
            ay=-40  
        ))

fig.update_layout(annotations=annotations)

fig.show()

which gives you

Adapt this to your data.
 Updated answer 
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

data = {
    'Time': [datetime(2023, 5, 1, 12) + timedelta(minutes=10 * i) for i in range(20)],
    'Power': [5, 3, 2, -1, -2, -3, 0, 0, 5, 2, -1, -2, 3, 5, 0, 0, -1, 0, 2, 3]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df['Duration'] = df['Time'].diff()
df['Shifted Duration'] = df['Duration'].shift(-1)
df['Group'] = (df['Power'] > 0).astype(int).cumsum()

positive_durations = df[df['Power'] > 0].groupby('Group')['Shifted Duration'].sum()
negative_durations = df[df['Power'] <= 0].groupby('Group')['Shifted Duration'].sum()

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Time'], y=df['Power'], mode='lines+markers', name='Power'))

annotations = []
for group, duration in positive_durations.items():
    start_time = df[df['Group'] == group]['Time'].min()
    if duration.total_seconds() > 60:
        annotations.append(dict(
            x=start_time,
            y=0,  
            xref="x",
            yref="y",
            text=f"Pos: {duration}",
            showarrow=True,
            arrowhead=1,
            ax=0,
            ay=30  
        ))

for group, duration in negative_durations.items():
    start_time = df[df['Group'] == group]['Time'].min()
    if duration.total_seconds() > 60:
        annotations.append(dict(
            x=start_time,
            y=0,  
            xref="x",
            yref="y",
            text=f"Neg: {duration}",
            showarrow=True,
            arrowhead=1,
            ax=0,
            ay=-40  
        ))

fig.update_layout(annotations=annotations)
fig.show()


I'm sorry to bother you, you've been very helpful, but I need to ask you something else. Grouping is a very convenient function and I tried to use it to group all periods one after another: the first period (+ or -) lasted n time, the second period (- or +) lasted n time. I tried by adding a line: positive_durations = df[df['[PLC]OBJ_TRANS.IN_HS_P.V'] > 0].groupby('Group')['Shifted Duration'].sum(), but nothing worked. How does this function work?

Can you check if my updated answer solves this?

it seems to me that I asked the question incorr. and misled you.
G - group
String:df['G']=(df['Power']>0).astype(int).cumsum()
Creates a col 'G' in the DF and assigns a num value of the G in each row. Where the value of Power is>0, the G is assigned according to the principle of n+1, and where the value of Power<=0, the G is n throughout all values until the next line of Power>0. How make the value of G n change only when the sign (plus or minus) of the Power col changes? The first 5 >0 values are in G 0, then the values 6,7 are <=0 and they are in G 1, then 8,9 are >0 in G 3, etc.
